# Number of Combinations with limited supply

Tags: combinatorics

It's Friday, and I'm tired, so there possibly a trivial solution that I am overlooking ...

The problem is the following: I have ($n=2$) two kinds of things, say Apples and Bananas, and I choose $k$ of these, not minding the order in which I take them.

What is the possible number of combinations, given that I only have $\alpha$ Apples and $\beta$ Bananas?
($\alpha+\beta>k$, but typically $\alpha<=k$ or $\beta<=k$ or both). And how many solutions are there that include exactly $\gamma<=\alpha$ Apples?

(I think that without the limits the solution would be an application of the multiset-number/stars-and-bars, with n and k. However, these solutions assume a unlimited supply of fruit, and I cannot see a way to adapt that these results to my limits.)

Comment: Are the apples distinguishable?

Comment: They're Fuji and Granny Smith apples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing $\gamma$ apples you must have $k-\gamma$ bananas (if $\gamma \ge k-\beta$).  That is the only way, unless you are going to distinguish the apples and distinguish the bananas, in which case there are ${\alpha \choose \gamma}{\beta \choose k-\gamma}$ ways.

Add these up over $\gamma$ and you get your answer: either

$$\sum_{\gamma=\max(0,k-\beta)}^{\min(k,\alpha)} 1 $$

if you are not going to distinguish the apples and distinguish the bananas, or

$$\sum_{\gamma=\max(0,k-\beta)}^{\min(k,\alpha)} {\alpha \choose \gamma}{\beta \choose k-\gamma} $$

if you are.

The first of these is equal to $\alpha+\beta+1-k$, provided that $  0 \le k - \beta < \alpha \le k$.

Comment: In fact, I realized I have to distinguish the apples and bananas only after writing the question (and reading your answer).